# R reading files to iterate through them, final iteration command will not work due to file handling error

Tags: r, debugging, matrix

I have written 100 two-columned matrices into their own separate text  files and now need to read the contents back into a list of 100 matrices such that I can conduct the command at the bottom of this entry "ComputeStepSize". My code is as follows:

I write each of the 100 matrices in "listofmatrices1" into their own files.

```
      for(i in 1:length(listofmatrices1)){
         write.table(listofmatrices1[[i]], file=(paste("traj1", as.character(i), ".txt", sep="")), row.names=FALSE, sep="\t")
      }
```

use the sys() command to make a list of the files such that I can read them with following commands.

```
      individualmatrices1<-system("ls /Users/Deirdreclarkson/rpractice/traj1*", intern=TRUE)
      readTrajectory1 <- function(traj1) {
         a <- read.table(traj1, sep="\t", header=TRUE)
         return(a)
      }
```

I read the matrices into an empty list using "readTrajectory".

```
      trajectorieslist1<-vector("list", 100)
      for (i in 1:length(individualmatrices1)){
        val1 <- readTrajectory1(individualmatrices1[i])
        trajectorieslist1[[i]]<-val1
      }
```

the header of one of the matrices in the list:

```
               X        Y
             112.4563 112.4563
             110.1210 110.1210
             109.2143 109.2143
             108.1806 108.1806
             107.3700 107.3700
```

I'm iterating through the matrix 2 columns and measuring the difference between each consecutive value.

```
      ComputeStepSize<-function(table){
        deltastepY <- diff(table[,2][seq(1,length(table[,2]), 2)])
        print(deltastepY)
        deltastepX <- diff(table[,1][seq(1,length(table[,2]), 2)])
        print(deltastepX)
        overalldelta<-sqrt(deltastepY**2+deltastepX**2)
        return(overalldelta)
      }
```

Read the individual matrices using a for loop.

```
      for (i in 100){
        finalsteplist1<-ComputeStepSize(trajectorieslist1[i])
      }
```

Issue

```
      Error in table[, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I don't understand why this is happening as I have told the "ComputeStepSize" command that there are only 2 columns- "diff(table[,2][seq(1,length(table[,2]), 2)])".

Can any one spot where in my file-handling I've gone wrong such that this is happening?

I have assigned the read.table of one of the files to a variable "a" and tried ComputeStepSize(a).This returns a generic debugger:

```
          function (x, ...) UseMethod("print")
```

but I can't print deltastepX or Y while they're being made as it causes the command won't operate on them to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>       Error in table[, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions
> ```
>
> … Can any one spot where in my file-handling I've gone wrong such that this
>   is happening?

You didn't go wrong in your file-handling, you just used a general subscripting operator `[`…`]` in

```
        finalsteplist1<-ComputeStepSize(trajectorieslist1[i])
```

(yielding a *sublist of the list*) instead of the operator `[[`…`]]` used to select a single element:

```
        finalsteplist1<-ComputeStepSize(trajectorieslist1[[i]])
```